# tikzjax badly clips when two pictures together

Tags: tikz, tikzjax

I am using the `tikzjax` extension to enable the latex `tikz` package to be used within a php script. The minimal example below demonstrates the problem. The script `<head>` uses the information from `https://tikzjax.com/`. Then follows the exact same `tikzpicture` except the positioning of the node B in both cases (the second case is the reflection of the first). The problem is the `\clip` doesn't work in the second case. If the first case is commented out, then it works. Here's a picture of the output from my browser:

[image: output of the script below]

The problem is tha the clip seems to follow the same kind of path in the second instance as for the first. How can this situation be solved, could it be a `tikzjax` bug? Are we not supposed to have more than one such diagram rendered in a php page?

```
<?php

echo '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tikzjax.com/v1/fonts.css">
<script src="https://tikzjax.com/v1/tikzjax.js"></script></head>';


echo 'Top node at (0,3)
<script type="text/tikz">
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,3);
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\begin{scope}
\clip (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\draw (0,0.5)--++(0.5,0)--++(0,-1)--++(-1,0)--++(0,1)--++(1,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
</script>
<br><br>
';


echo 'Top node at (0,-3)
<script type="text/tikz">
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (C) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,-3);
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\begin{scope}
\clip (A)--(B)--(C)--(A);
\draw (0,0.5)--++(0.5,0)--++(0,-1)--++(-1,0)--++(0,1)--++(1,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
</script>
';


?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this is really relevant to PHP since all the posted code is doing is echoing the scripts. That should work the same if it was hard coded on a HTML page, no?

Comment: @M.Eriksson Fair point! I don't know what tags to otherwise give. There is no tikzjax tag. Shall I remove the php tag then?

Comment: Yes, please remove the PHP tag and also post the generated code (since that's the only thing the browser will get) instead of the PHP source. Since the question is about how to use a specific library/extension, have you tried finding some support forum or similar? Or even add it as an issue on their github if it doesn't behave as expected.